# Authenticate php site on linux box against multiple windows AD domains and controllers

Tags: php, active-directory, ldap, centos, single-sign-on

We're currently implementing a linux web server within an enterprise windows environment to host our new Drupal intranet site. We would like our users to have seamless integration, so SSO is essential. This on it's own isn't too tricky. The confusion starts when we add the windows domain structure.

We have offices all around the globe. Each of these offices has it's own network and domain. A global WAN connects all of these networks, with a resource domain overseeing it all. This is all working, as I can ping each of the domain controllers from the web server box sat on this network.

What we're struggling to clarify is how do we configure the Cent OS 6.3 web server to grab the remote user's logon credentials.

Web server is Cent OS 6.3, running Apache 2.2 and php 5.3.

Windows DC's range from 2000 to possibly the latest.

Clients are primarily XP users running IE8, but some are Win 7 running IE10.

Please let me know if I've left anything out that you need to know.

Comment: did you ever find an answer to this?

Comment: Using winbind the system is a member of the resource domain. Using mod_auth_ntml we turn auth on in apache, to return a REMOTE_USER variable in php and trigger SSO. The php app has a user setup for each domain that's a member of the global WAN. A user hits the site, credentials are passed from browser to apache. If it' validates, the site uses the domain/username in REMOTE_USER and triggers an LDAP query to their own AD to get the rest of their details. Our sys guru has spent hours trying to get kerberos working instead of NTLM, but there's a quirk in our AD that's stopping it from working.